# Can your partner go alone when you decide trump?

Tags: euchre

The player to my right has the deal, the hand is dealt and everybody passes, the dealer turns down a card in a red suit. I'm next to make it, I have 9 & 10 of clubs and an off suit ace, I think my partner has a good hand. So I make it clubs, I made it right into hand.

The question is can he order me up and go alone? The other two player disagreed. We played the hand and got all the tricks. Hope you can answer, will try give more detail if needed.

Comment: What game are you asking about? Overall this question is very confusing

Comment: Since the question is closed, I will put this out as a comment unless and until it is reopened. The other players are correct, only the player who decides trump can go alone. You decided trump so only uou can go alone.

Comment: It's worth noting that ordering up only refers to the first round, when the dealer would pick up the face up card, since this is what you are ordering up.

Comment: Your partner already passed, so once you make it clubs, that's it. What is there to even ask?

Comment: @Nij They are asking if they can call the suit but their partner declare going alone, the answer is no, since only the person who makes trump can go alone.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only the player that decides what trump is has the option to go alone. For your partner to go alone, you would have needed to pass, and your opponent would also need to pass.

Its also worth noting that the term ordering up is only in the first round of deciding trump, when there is a card face up that the dealer will pick up when they are ordered to. Once the dealer turns the card down, there is nothing to order up.